# bash: preventing a redirected function's errors from mixing with output

Tags: bash

Want to get user's input from a function. However, the prompt ("Please answer y or n." in this case) is also included in the return value.

```
#!/bin/bash

input() {
    while true; do
        read -p "input y/n: " yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) yn="y"; break;;
            [Nn]* ) yn="n"; break;;
            * ) echo "Please answer y or n.";;
        esac
    done

    echo $yn
}

val=$(input)
echo "val is: $val"
```

If input an error value first and here is the results:

```
input y/n: other
input y/n: y
val is: Please answer y or n.
y
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Echo your error to stderr (FD 2), not stdout (the default, FD 1):

```
echo "Please answer y or n." >&2
```

Answer (score 3):

Better use a common global variable to pass values between the function and the caller. It's more efficient than summoning subshells with command substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash

input() {
    while true; do
        read -p "input y/n: " __
        case "$__" in
            [Yy]* ) __="y"; break;;
            [Nn]* ) __="n"; break;;
            * ) echo "Please answer y or n.";;
        esac
    done
}

input; val=$__
echo "val is: $val"
```

Comment: Agreed as to efficiency. Using a shared variable can get interesting, though, if you have multiple or nested functions doing it; I tend to pass the variable name as the first argument when taking this approach.

Comment: As of `bash` 4.3, you can use a named reference to simplify this. Add `declare -n __=$1` to the beginning of the function, then make the call `input val`. After `input` returns, `val` will contain the answer. (4.3 was released in Feb 2014; I'm not sure how widely adopted it is as of Aug 2014.)

Comment: ...for bash releases not _quite_ that current, I tend to use something more like `printf -v "$1" '%s' "$__"` to copy the value into a named variable, but @chepner's approach is definitely the Right Thing going forward.

Comment: @chepner I was quite happy about `-n` when I knew the feature even before 4.3 was released. It was quite a good alternative to the general assignment builtin I called `setvalue` that I proposed but was declined. However 4.3 has made some changes before it was released and it crippled my application. It just doesn't give me the appetite to endorse new features :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mentioned the feature to you and mklement0 once.

Comment: @konsolebox, I'm sure you did; I was also aware of them well before bash 4.3's release on account of chatter in the #bash IRC channel, but I don't make a habit of tracking every situation in which I've heard a thing mentioned.